# In Angular 2.0.0-beta.0 map() and filter() are missing from a form input's Observable

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

In Angular 2.0.0-alpha.47 the `Observable` returned from calling  `formInput.valueChanges()` had all the higher order functions i.e  I could do something like this;

```
this.search.valueChanges
 .debounceTime(150)
 .map(x=>return x+1)
 .switchMap(text => this.youtube.search(text));
```

I'm now using 2.0.0-beta.0 and the `Observable` returned from `this.search.valueChanges()` no longer has all the methods. I can only subscribe. I can no longer call map(), filter() etc.

Does anyone know if this is the expected behaviour for form inputs now?

Comment: [`valueChanges`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/common/forms/model.ts#L88) returns an Observable (that's why you can subscribe to it...). What problem are you actually having?

Comment: @EricMartinez I can longer call any higher order functions on the returned observable as I could when it was on alpha. I will edit my question to make it a little clearer.

Comment: probably going to always be the case - not just early betas (same in beta.12)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

import Rxjs like this :

```
Import * as Rx from "rxjs/Rx";
```

The operators will be available.

When you use Observable class .. prefix it with Rx. ( Rx.Observable )

Comment: That was it. Thanks Mourad. All the code examples I was looking at for the beta were using 
'import {Observable, Observer} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/operator/map';
'

Comment: I have had the same issue .. i spent 4 hours to fix the problem .. 

The transition from Rxjs 4 to 5 it's not easy .. 

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS/blob/master/MIGRATION.md

Answer (score 4):

Did you try to import this:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

See this issue for more details https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5632

Hope it helps you,
Thierry