# Ionic 2 - Importing/Injecting Angular 2 HTTP Component

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

I have an ionic 2 app that I've been testing using local data. Now, I am attempting to make some Ajax requests to my api to get the data.

In my `app.js` file, I am defining my component like so:

```
import {UserProvider} from './providers/user-provider';
...
    @App({
      templateUrl: 'build/app.html',
      providers: [UserProvider]
    })
```

Then, my `user-provider.js` file is defined like so:

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, httpInjectables} from 'angular2/http';

@Injectable()
export class UserProvider {
    constructor(http: Http) {
        http.get('www.someURL.com').toRx().map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe(data => console.log(data));
    }
}
```

Then, lastly, I am initializing my "Sign Up" view with my `signup.js` file:

```
import {Page, NavController} from 'ionic/ionic';
import {TabsPage} from '../tabs/tabs';
import {UserProvider} from '../../providers/user-provider';

@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/signup/signup.html'
})
export class SignupPage {
  constructor(nav: NavController, userProvider: UserProvider) {
    this.userProvider = userProvider;
    this.nav = nav;
  }
}
```

My expected result is that on initialization of my signup view, the `UserProvider` will be injected. As such, it's constructor will run, which will fire off the `http.get` function within the `UserProvider`'s constructor. I should then see a network call in my browsers network tab.

However, I'm getting this error:

```
EXCEPTION: Error during instantiation of UserProvider! (SignupPage -> UserProvider)

app.bundle.js:33693 TypeError: http.get(...).toRx is not a function
    at new UserProvider (app.bundle.js:60706)
```

Why is `http.get.toRx()` causing an error? I initially tried this with promises like so:

```
http.get('www.someURL.com').then(() => {
            console.log('test');
        });
```

but that throws a similar error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In angular2-beta0 `http.get()` already returns an `Observable`, you don't need to call its former `.toRx()` method, you can just directly call `.map()` and such.

Comment: Interesting - So, calling `.map` directly gives me this error:

`TypeError: http.get(...).map is not a function`

Is there an issue with the importing of the `http` component? Should it be included elsewhere maybe? I initially thought it had to be included in the `bootstrap` function call, but my ionic (cordova) app doesn't use the `bootstrap` function.

Comment: The `.map()` Rx function probably has to be imported. See the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34581471/angular2-http-is-missing-map-function for more information. It's possible that a `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';` would be sufficient if everything else is set up correctly.