# Run method after array is updated

Tags: angular

I have a service where I fetch some data form Firebase. That service offers an observable, which I then subscribe to in my component class. When the data is loaded, and sent to the array, the DOM updates with new data, but I need to run some javascript and jQuery code again after the DOM update which I can't figure out how to.

My service method looks like this:

```
getSubjects() {
    return new Observable(observer => {
      this.subjectsRef.orderByChild('name').on("value", snapshot => {
        var tempArr = [];
        snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
          var subject = {
            name: data.val().name,
            imgUrl: data.val().imgUrl,
            description: data.val().description,
            teachers: data.val().teachers
          }
          tempArr.push(subject);
        });
        observer.next(tempArr);
      });
    // this.broadcastUpdate();
  });
  }
```

And my component:

```
export class SubjectsCmp implements AfterViewInit, OnInit, OnChanges {

  constructor(
    private _subjectsService: SubjectsService
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._subjectsService.getSubjects().subscribe( subjects => this.subjects = subjects);
  }
}
```

I've looked a bit at the [documentation for RxJS](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/subscribe.md) but to no avail. I thought I could rewrite it to follow the example they give::

```
var subscription = source.subscribe(
  function (x) {
    console.log('Next: %s', x);
  },
  function (err) {
    console.log('Error: %s', err);
  },
  function () {
    console.log('Completed');
  });
```

But 'Completed' never fires.

Angular 2's onChanges observer only responds to changes caused by input events, so that won't work either.
Basically I just need to run a method after the array is populated, I'm thinking I'm missing something obvious?

Comment: You need to run something after Angular's change detection updates the DOM?  If so, try calling setTimeout() after you update `this.subjects`.  Do your additional work in the setTimeout() callback function.

Comment: Could you provide an example @MarkRajcok. Also, will this fire every time the data is updated or only once?

Comment: `ngOnInit() { this._subjectsService.getSubjects().subscribe( subjects => { this.subjects = subjects;  setTimeout(function() { ...run your stuff here... }, 0); } );  }`.  It will fire whenever your observable has something new to send.

Comment: @MarkRajcok for some reason it fires before the data is loaded and is sent. Putting a log statement in the timeout function and one in the service, the log in the service prints before the timeout

Comment: That sounds like it is working as I expected... you request data from your service, then sometime later the data comes in and the observable notifies any subscribers.  The one subscriber updates the component's `subject` property, and then uses `setTimeout()` to give Angular a chance to run change detection and update the DOM. Then your setTimeout callback function is called/executed.

Comment: @MarkRajcok sorry, I meant it the other way around. The timeout fires before the service

Comment: Is that because of some initial subscription notification?  If so, in the setTimeout callback, just handle the case where `this.subjects` is empty.

Comment: I don't know if I am using the Observer class in the wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

`subscribe()` method returns **Subscriber**, which inherits `add()` method that you can use:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this._subjectsService.getSubjects()
    .subscribe( subjects => this.subjects = subjects)
    // add new subscription
    .add(() => console.log('Completed', this.subjects));
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It never fires. I'm starting to suspect something is wrong with the way I'm using my observable?

Comment: Make sure you're [importing the operators](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34581771/1876949). I'd also suggest you look into [generating observables](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html#categorized) and avoid `new Observable()` if you're just starting with them...