# How can we add another subscribe action in the http observable in angularjs2?

Tags: typescript, angular

I am new to Angular2. I have a LoginComponent which takes in an action called submitLogin from a submit button. When clicked, it will send the username and password (via the UserService) to the API server (with the help of UtilService). If the server responds OK, it will return with a token, and we would save it locally and redirect it.

So far, I have managed to send the username and password and save the token. But, I am confused on how we can add another action in the LoginComponent so that we can redirect the user. (I have added a comment in the login.component.ts below to clarify what I would like to do).

Feel free to let me know if I am not making myself clear.

Here are the codes that I have:

login.component.ts has the following:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {NgForm}    from 'angular2/common';
import {UserService} from '../services/user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'login',
  templateUrl: './components/login/login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./components/login/login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  public username: string;
  public password: string;
  public loginResult: string;

  constructor(private _userService: UserService) {}
  ngOnInit() { }
  submitLogin() {
    var p = this._userService.login(this.username, this.password);
    // HOW TO: 
    // I know p is an observable. But, is it possible to add a condition as follow:
    // if p is success, then redirect
    // if p failed, then return
  }
}
```

user.service.ts:

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {UtilsService} from './utils.service';

@Injectable()

export class UserService {
  constructor(private _utils: UtilsService) { }

  login(username: string, password: string) {
    var request = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + password) },
      url: '/auth/',
      data: null
    };

    return this._utils.api(request).subscribe(
      data => this.setAccessToken(data.json().access_token),
      err => console.log(err)
    );
    var promise = this._utils.api(request);
    promise.then((response) => {
      this.setAccessToken(response.token);
    });
  }

}
```

utils.service.ts:

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, Headers} from 'angular2/http';

@Injectable()

export class UtilsService {
  private apiUrl: string;
  constructor(public http: Http) {
    this.apiUrl = '/api/1';
  }
  api(request: any) {
    var headers = new Headers();
    var url = this.apiUrl + request.url;

    if(request.headers) {
      for(var key in request.headers) {
        headers.append(key, request.headers[key]);
      }
    }

    if(!request.type || request.type === 'GET') {
      return this.http.get(url, { headers: headers });
    }

    if(request.type === 'POST') {
      return this.http.post(url, request.data, { headers: headers });
    }

    if(request.type === 'PUT') {
      return this.http.put(url, request.data, { headers: headers });
    }

    if(request.type === 'DELETE') {
      return this.http.delete(url, { headers: headers });
    }
    return false;

  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you make your UserService.login() return observable (not subscriber, as it does now) you can subscribe to it in LoginComponent

```
export class UserService {
  login(username: string, password: string) {

    return this._utils.api(request)
      .map(response => response.json())
    );
  }
}

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  submitLogin() {
    var p = this._userService
      .login(this.username, this.password)
      .subscribe(

        // success
        (data) => { 
          this._userService.setAccessToken(data.access_token); 
          // redirect here...
        }, 

        // error
        (error) => {}, 

        // completed
        () => {}  
      )
  }
}
```

Comment: You can also use `add()` method to add another subscription to the subscriber that `subscribe()` method returns. [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34692422/1876949), but I believe we should get used to services that return obeservables (:

Comment: Thanks alot for the clarification! @Sasxa, I was wondering for the `(error)` somehow I am getting like a `e {_body: "{"error":"User was not found."}", status: 404, statusText: "Ok", headers: e, type: 2…}`. How can I get the error message "User was not found" from there? Thanks!

Comment: Both success and error handlers have [Response](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/Response-class.html) as arugment, you can call it's `json()` method to get the message

Comment: thanks for the reply. That's what I thought, too. In the utils.service.ts above, I have added `.map((res: Response) => res.json())` at the end of the return lines. I managed to get the success return (`data`) as a JSON object. But, somehow, the `error` still returns a Response. Is there anything I should do? Thanks alot again!

Comment: You can set the access token directly in the UserService login method (as the OP is trying to do) using a `.do`, instead of having to make a second call to the service from the LoginComponent: `return this._utils.api(request).map(res => res.json()).do(data => this.setAccessToken(data.token));`. Then the LoginComponent subscribes as usual.